# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How can I solve this improper integral?

$$
\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\,dx
$$
using the following result:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.
$$

Comment: Sub $x=u^2$ and integrate by parts.

Comment: I get $$ -x^{1/2}e^{-x} - \int_0^\infty -1/2x^{-1/2}e^{-x}$$. I have already solved that inside integral which is $$\sqrt{pi}/2$$ and the limit of the rest of the stuff is 0 making the final answer $$\sqrt{pi}/2$$. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes it is...but then you did *not* use the hint Ron gave you...

Comment: See also: [How to calculate the definite integral $\int\limits_0^\infty \sqrt{x} e^{-x} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1795182)

Answer (score 4):

$$x=y^2\implies dx=2y\,dy$$

and your integral is

$$I:=\int\limits_0^\infty 2y^2e^{-y^2}dy$$

Now by parts

$$u=y\;\;,\;\;u'=1\\v'=2ye^{-y^2}\;\;,\;\;v=-e^{-y^2}$$

so

$$I=\left.-ye^{-y^2}\right|_0^\infty+\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

Comment: I think the integral I has the wrong power $2y^2$ should be 2y because we have $\sqrt(x)$ not x

Comment: @arcolombo It's usually hard to remember after all this time...but in this case it is not: you're forgetting the $\;2ydy\;$ : $$\sqrt x\,dx\to y\cdot2y\,dy=2y^2\,dy$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ 2 \big( \frac{ \sqrt[ ]{ \pi }erf( \sqrt[]{x}) }{4}- \frac{\sqrt[]{x} e^{-x} }{2}  \big)+c$$
Will be the indefinite integral with erf being the Gauss error function. using the bounds leaves you with $$\frac{ \sqrt[]{ \pi } }{2} $$